# Можно ли смайлики считать знаками препинания?

Tags: интернет

Сейчас сложно представить себе интернет-переписку без смайликов. Они облегчают жизнь, когда ты не видишь и не слышишь интонации собеседника.
А как вы думаете, могут ли смайлики стать официальными знаками препинания? Ведь с ними действительно порой удобнее.

Answer (score 3):

В наше время трудно что-либо прогнозировать. Всё может быть. Но я считаю, что этого не должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток К вопросу: если рассматривать буквенное обозначение самого примиттвного смайлика - ":)", то он состоит, в том числе и из знака препинания ":", значит такие "неологизмы" нашего века можно приравнять к знакам  припинания.

Comment: Буквенное обозначение — ":)"? Неужели?

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, их стоит считать знаками препинания :) В большинстве случаев они служат знаком конца предложения. Это моя личная позиция, но я руководствуюсь тем, что если поставить после смайла точку, то получится какая-то фигня :D. А значит, раз он способен заменить точку, то и сам он является знаком препинания.